# Runtime Error 3464 when trying to use simple VB code to open a query

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a button that, when clicked, checks to see what the value of a particular option is. If that option is selected, open a specific query. I can't figure out why this is giving me an error:

```
'PKG query
    If (Me.opt_Pkg.Value = -1) Then

        DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qry_InventoryModule_PKG")

    End If
```

I also tried this, but it gave me the same error:

```
'PKG query
    If Me.opt_MarsSAP_Pkg = -1 Then

        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_InventoryModule_PKG"

    End If
```

Comment: @JacobH Yep. This is a problem I'm having in an MS Access DB.

Comment: Not to ask the obvious, but do you have a query saved in that database exactly called "qry_InventoryModule_PKG"?

Comment: @JacobH yup, I just double checked too.

Comment: Your query opens without any problems, right?
Make a backup, and delete all the data in your table and see if it works?

Comment: 1) It is most helpful to those answering your question if you include the error code description along with the number... add that detail to the question text. 2)  A simple web search reveals that Access error 3464 is a "Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression".  2a)  "Criteria expression" immediately implies that the problem is in the query itself, not in your VBA code.

Comment: Why are you opening a query? Is this an action SQL? To do what? Edit question to post the SQL.